# Rquest for member 'push_back' vectors c++

Tags: c++, vector, compiler-errors

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
const int NMAX=10;
vector <int>sir[NMAX];
int s[10];

int main()
{
    int n, i;
    cin>>n;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        cin>>s[i];
    sir.push_back(s);
    for(i=0;i<sir[0].push_back();i++)
        cout<<sir[0][i]<<" ";
    return 0;
}
```

And at line 15 I have an error:

> request for a member 'push_back' in 'sir', which is not-class type 'std::vector[10]'.

Why do I get this error?

Comment: `sir[0].push_back()` pushes back nothing. `push_back`here requires an `int` to push back. `push_back` also returns `void`, so there is no return value to compare `i` against.

Comment: There are more than one ways to fix the compiler problem(s). It's not clear from our code what you are attempting to do.

Comment: i want to have a 2D int vector

Comment: @B.Botzki Look at your own code carefully -- `{whatever_type} sir[NMAX];`.  The `sir` is an array of {whatever_type}.  Then you do this:  `sir.`.  There is no `.` operator that can be applied to arrays.  So your issue is *not* `std::vector`.

Comment: The first problem here is that from the declaration `vector <int>sir[NMAX];`, `sir` is an _array of vectors_, not a single vector. C-style arrays obviously don't have a `push_back()` method which is where your compiler error is coming from. You should also ask yourself what `i<sir[0].push_back()` is supposed to do, `push_back` expects an argument and returns `void`

Comment: It would help us give you a better answer if you told us what you want `sir` to represent and what exactly you are trying to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

Either go with arrays or vectors, but there's no reason to mix them.

In addition, it looks like you meant `.size()` when you do `.push_back()`

Assuming you want vectors, we can make this a 2D vector and fix the `.size()` mistake:

```
const int NMAX=10;
vector <vector<int>> sir;
vector<int> s(10);

int main()
{
    int n, i;
    cin>>n;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        cin >> s[i];
    sir.push_back(s);
    for(i=0;i < sir[0].size();i++)
        cout<<sir[0][i]<<" ";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: [Seems to work](https://ideone.com/aAJaUd) (at least it should compile)

Comment: Although there are a couple of things to watch out for now.  `NMAX` is no longer used, and you may get a segfault if `n` is greater than **or equal to** `10`.

Comment: A segfault would be fine. It's all the other possible outcomes of this UB that you need to worry about